# Do all races in WoW have same strength maximums?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Say I choose to be a gnome, the race with the least starting strength points... And say I want to be a warrior.

Will I be able to max out the strength later on, so it matches the one of a Tauren? Or will Taurens always have more strength than me?

Basically, I'm asking if the starting stats matter only for the start of the game, and normalize later on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will always be the base difference, but since the difference is so low (10 stats with 4000+ str at 85) it will not matter much, what is of more importance is the racial abilities that come with each race. For example if you choose to play a tank the Tauren gets 5% health increase, at high levels this will make a bigger difference compared to base stam.